# NFA for the language that accepts binary strings ending with 00

Tags: automata, finite-automata

This is the question:

> 1.7. Give state diagrams of NFAs with the specified number of states recognizing each
> of the following languages. In all parts, the alphabet is {0,1}.

> a. The language {w| w ends with 00} with three states

This is how my professor answered it:

[image: my professor answer]

But this is the answer I found on web:

[image: answer on web]

But I think the second one should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer is incorrect. The automaton does not accept, for example, the input word $0100$. In fact, the first automaton misses at least all words in the language that are not of the form $1^*0^*$.

The second answer is correct. It is not hard to prove it. Can you try?